# Terraform apply results in Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I try to apply terraform plan with `terraform apply`. But when I run the command I get the following error

```
Error: Error building AzureRM Client: Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI: 
No Authorization Tokens were found - 
please ensure the Azure CLI is installed and then log-in with `az login`.
```

I do have the Azure CLI installed and I'm logged in with `az login`. When I run `az login` I am redirected to the landing page where I am able to log in just fine.

Also `terraform init` works without any problems.

Below my terraform file:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "1.38.0"
}
```

I also tried to provide subscription and tenant IDs but it didn't help:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "1.38.0"

  subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  tenant_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
}
```

Comment: That provider version is deprecated, and could easily be incompatible with any recent version of the CLI. Try updating to `~> 2.0` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Error: Error building AzureRM Client: Error populating Client ID from
> the Azure CLI:  No Authorization Tokens were found -  please ensure
> the Azure CLI is installed and then log-in with `az login`.

This ***error is due to the Azure CLI version that you are using*** . There was a ***breaking change in the Azure CLI version `2.30.0`*** where ***Azure migrated the authentication from `ADAL` to `MSAL`***. For which if you are ***using Azure CLI latest and Terraform azurerm old*** then , it will ***fail in authentication which will result in the error***.

To ***Fix the problem*** you will have to use the ***latest Azure CLI version i.e. `2.32.0`*** and also ***at the same time try to use the terraform latest `azurerm` Provider i.e. `2.92.0`***.

To ***Upgrade CLI version , You can run `az upgrade` command*** and in ***terraform you can use the below :***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.92.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
}
```

You can refer these ***Similar Github Issues*** are well : ***[`Issue 1`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20356)*** and [***`Issue 2`***](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14560)