# Azure: CLI using multiple Versions

Tags: azure, azure-cli

For [some Dependencies reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736802/7073340) with Terraform (using azure cli internally). I'm trying to use multiple versions of azure cli in my machine. `e.g, 2.30.0 ,2.22.0`

Depends on the need we are planning to change the version whenever required. But I couldn't find a way to change the azure cli version.

I can find a way to install [older version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13331#issuecomment-862122089) but that has to be done by uninstalling the newer version and installing the older version. But I don't want to uninstall it, I want to keep the version(s) and use the different version whenever needed.

Is this possible in azure-cli ?

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible. I would use containers to solve this issue.

Comment: @CSharpRocks can you explain a bit around your solution to use containers to call different azure cli while the terraform files are in my local PC. How do we can achieve that ?

Comment: I would either copy the Terraform files into the container or map a volume to the local folder like this:  docker run --rm -it -v d:\Terraform:/myTerraform busybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *As far as I know and as per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) you can't use different versions of **Azure CLI** in same system at a time.*
- *As you already know you need to uninstall the older and install the newer when needed.*
- *As suggested by [CSharpRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks) you can use containers to use multiple versions at a time.*
- *You can Raise a [Feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community) and [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/) for further usage.*

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I have submitted the issue as a [feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22669)