# Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI: No Authorization Tokens were found

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli

When I run Terraform Plan I am getting the following error message.

> Error building AzureRM Client: Error populating Client ID from the
> Azure CLI: No Authorization Tokens were found

I ran 'az login' to log in and 'az account set --subscription' to set the right subscription.

I saw other postings and tried running 'az account get-access-token' and it returns the accessToken without any errors.

```
terraform {
  # backend "azurerm" {
  #   key = "terraform.tfstate"
  # }
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  
  version                    = "= 1.31.0"
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

Terraform and Az cli versions below

```
 $ az --version azure-cli                         2.38.0



$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.31
+ provider.azurerm v1.31.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error building AzureRM Client: Error populating Client ID from the Azure CLI: No Authorization Tokens were found

This Error occurs due to versions of  ***Terraform azurerm providers and CLI***. The authentication was switched over by Azure from ***ADAL to MSAL.***  If you are using recent version of Azure CLI with older version of Terraform's Azurerm this may cause an authentication failure and error.

***To fix this issues use the upgraded versions both azure cli and terrform azurerm providers.***

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

**[Terraform azurerm version link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs)**

Similar kind of error also solved,you can check this [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731154/terraform-apply-results-in-error-populating-client-id-from-the-azure-cli) by Ansuman Bal.

Comment: Hi unfortunately it did not help..

Comment: Could you please try to run the az account clear and run again